How to convert .BX/QLI/CQP/HQC/PLT/ART file to .jpg format using python?
I'm building a project using pyembroidery in python to convert as many embroidery and sewing files to thumbnail images (.jpg). I need to expand the file formats to include .BX/QLI/CQP/HQC/PLT/ART. Ultimately my ask is for support to expand the pyembroidery library to include these additional formats, see link below.
https://github.com/EmbroidePy/pyembroidery
Anyone available to support or suggestions for someone that can? TIA
